# Error response from daemon: client and server don't have same version docker 1.17

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-registry

What is the right docker version for the server <1.17>?
The version 1.7.0 is 1.19

Answer (score 0):

the best version is docker 1.5.0

```
sudo apt-get install -y lxc-docker-1.5.0
```